# Firebase Storage - "ref is not a function" error in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm working on a **Firebase Cloud Function** that processes a Zoop **API response**, extracts an image in **base64 format**, and attempts to upload it to **Firebase Storage**. However, I encountered an issue with the **ref function**, which is resulting in an error stating that **ref** **is not a function**. I've tried various approaches, including changing the way I reference the storage, but the issue persists. Any insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const { getStorage, ref, uploadString, getDownloadURL } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

exports.initResponse = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const db = getFirestore();
      const storage = getStorage();

      // Assuming Zoop response is a JSON object
      const zoopData = req.body;
      const reqId = zoopData.request_id;
      const result = zoopData.result;
      const base64Image = result.best_capture_image;
      console.log(base64Image);

      // Attempting to use ref function
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `best_capture_images/${reqId}.jpg`);
      await uploadString(storageRef, base64Image, "base64", { contentType: "image/jpg" });

      // Get the download URL
      const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

      console.log("Download URL:", downloadURL);

      // Further processing...

      res.status(200).json({ success: true, downloadURL });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image to Firebase Storage:", error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Error uploading image to Firebase Storage" });
    }
  });
});
```

**Additional Information:**

Node.js version: 18
Firebase SDK version: ^11.8.0

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I attempted to upload a base64 image from a Zoop API response to Firebase Storage in a Cloud Function. I used the uploadString method with the storageRef obtained from ref, but encountered an issue with 'ref is not a function.' I expected the image to be successfully uploaded, and I anticipated retrieving a valid download URL. However, the actual result was an error at the 'ref' step. I then tried using 'storage.ref' and subsequently faced issues with 'storage.ref' not being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

import the firebase admin sdk and initialize it

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();

exports.initResponse = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
```

than use a bucket to reference the storage and file

```
      const bucket = storage.bucket();
      const file = bucket.file(`best_capture_images/${reqId}.jpg`);
      await file.save(Buffer.from(base64Image, 'base64'), {
        metadata: { contentType: 'image/jpg' },
      });
```

get the download url

```
 const downloadURL = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '01-01-2222'
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but whenever I follow this method of admin.initializeApp() and deploy the function,
I get the error "Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error".
Please help, it is getting very confusing for me.

Comment: there is a syntax error in your code, try to use ESLint. post the entier code i'll have a look